# Varying parameters During a simulation in Simulink

Tags: time, parameters, simulink

I want to change the parameters of a block when the model is running and simultaneously see the changes in the output.

For eg.I have a sine block connected to a Scope.and when i start the simulation.I want to change the frequency of the sine wave and see the corresponding frequency changed wave on the scope output.I want to do this as i want to see how my model behaves for different frequencies.

Somebody please help me in this regard....Please comment and let me know..I will be grateful to who answer my question...

Comment: In some cases, you might consider using a time-varying signal instead of a constant.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you can vary a parameter during runtime depends on whether that parameter is *tunable*. Tunable parameters are those that can be changed after the simulation has started, however, you must pause the simulation to be able to do so.

Run your model simulation, then hit the pause button and open up the Sine block dialog. If the frequency edit box is not disabled you can change the frequency and resume the simulation.

If edit box is disabled it means that the frequency is not a tunable parameter. In this case, you can create your own Sine block using a MATLAB function call back and the `sin` function, by feeding the blocking the desired frequency.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, you could use a [`chirp signal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/chirpsignal.html).